# How to group by time interval in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataset looks like this:

```
KEY |Event_Type | metric | Time 
001 |event1     | 10     | 2016-05-01 10:50:51
002 |event2     | 100    | 2016-05-01 10:50:53
001 |event3     | 20     | 2016-05-01 10:50:55
001 |event1     | 15     | 2016-05-01 10:51:50
003 |event1     | 13     | 2016-05-01 10:55:30
001 |event2     | 12     | 2016-05-01 10:57:00
001 |event3     | 11     | 2016-05-01 11:00:01
```

I want to get all when the keys that verify this:

**"SUM of metric for a specific event"** > **threshold** during **5 minutes** .

This appear to me a perfect candidate for using the **Sliding Windows Functions** .

How can I do this with Spark SQL ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.0**

You can use [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@window(timeColumn:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,windowDuration:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (not to be mistaken with window functions). Depending on a variant it assigns timestamp, to one more, potentially overlapping buckets:

```scala
df.groupBy($"KEY", window($"time", "5 minutes")).sum("metric")

// +---+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
// |KEY|window                                       |sum(metric)|
// +---+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
// |001|[2016-05-01 10:50:00.0,2016-05-01 10:55:00.0]|45         |
// |001|[2016-05-01 10:55:00.0,2016-05-01 11:00:00.0]|12         |
// |003|[2016-05-01 10:55:00.0,2016-05-01 11:00:00.0]|13         |
// |001|[2016-05-01 11:00:00.0,2016-05-01 11:05:00.0]|11         |
// |002|[2016-05-01 10:50:00.0,2016-05-01 10:55:00.0]|100        |
// +---+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Spark < 2.0**

Lets start with example data:

```scala
import spark.implicits._  // import sqlContext.implicits._ in Spark < 2.0

val df = Seq(
  ("001", "event1", 10, "2016-05-01 10:50:51"),
  ("002", "event2", 100, "2016-05-01 10:50:53"),
  ("001", "event3", 20, "2016-05-01 10:50:55"),
  ("001", "event1", 15, "2016-05-01 10:51:50"),
  ("003", "event1", 13, "2016-05-01 10:55:30"),
  ("001", "event2", 12, "2016-05-01 10:57:00"),
  ("001", "event3", 11, "2016-05-01 11:00:01")
).toDF("KEY", "Event_Type", "metric", "Time")
```

I assume that event is identified by `KEY`. If this is not the case you can adjust `GROUP BY` / `PARTITION BY` clauses according to your requirements.

If you're interested in an aggregation with static window independent of data convert timestamps to a numeric data type and round

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{round, sum}

// cast string to timestamp_seconds
val ts = $"Time".cast("timestamp").cast("long")

// Round to 300 seconds interval
// In Spark >= 3.1 replace cast("timestamp") with 
val interval = (round(ts / 300L) * 300.0).cast("timestamp").alias("interval")

df.groupBy($"KEY", interval).sum("metric")

// +---+---------------------+-----------+
// |KEY|interval             |sum(metric)|
// +---+---------------------+-----------+
// |001|2016-05-01 11:00:00.0|11         |
// |001|2016-05-01 10:55:00.0|12         |
// |001|2016-05-01 10:50:00.0|45         |
// |003|2016-05-01 10:55:00.0|13         |
// |002|2016-05-01 10:50:00.0|100        |
// +---+---------------------+-----------+
```

If you're interested in a window relative to the current row use window functions:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Partition by KEY
// Order by timestamp 
// Consider window of -150 seconds to + 150 seconds relative to the current row
val w = Window.partitionBy($"KEY").orderBy("ts").rangeBetween(-150, 150)
df.withColumn("ts", ts).withColumn("window_sum", sum($"metric").over(w))

// +---+----------+------+-------------------+----------+----------+
// |KEY|Event_Type|metric|Time               |ts        |window_sum|
// +---+----------+------+-------------------+----------+----------+
// |003|event1    |13    |2016-05-01 10:55:30|1462092930|13        |
// |001|event1    |10    |2016-05-01 10:50:51|1462092651|45        |
// |001|event3    |20    |2016-05-01 10:50:55|1462092655|45        |
// |001|event1    |15    |2016-05-01 10:51:50|1462092710|45        |
// |001|event2    |12    |2016-05-01 10:57:00|1462093020|12        |
// |001|event3    |11    |2016-05-01 11:00:01|1462093201|11        |
// |002|event2    |100   |2016-05-01 10:50:53|1462092653|100       |
// +---+----------+------+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

For performance reasons this approach is useful only if data can partitioned into multiple separate groups. In Spark < 2.0.0 you'll also need `HiveContext` to make it work.

Comment: Hi i am using Java How to do the same operations in java and spark 2.1.0

Comment: @sathiyarajan Should be pretty much the same, excluding minor syntax differences.

Comment: Hi, then what is the approach for group bi-monthly, quarterly, 6-monthly?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window

thats the version of window function for pyspark

Answer (score 1):

For static boundary you can do following:

1) Transform (map, mapPartitions etc) Time value to form YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm where mm is rolled up at 5 minutes level. e.g. 01, 02, 03, 05 becomes 05; 16,17,18,19,20 becomes 20

2) Perform groupBy or reduceBy with event_type and time and perform your aggregation(Sum) on metrics

3) Perform filter transformation to filter metrics > 5

You can write above in spark rdd or dataframe(sql) in almost same way.

For other type of boundary where 00-05, 01-06, 02-07 you should try looking into concept of **sliding window**. If your data ingestion use case fits streaming pattern then Spark Streaming API will be perfect otherwise you can find custom solution like this one:
[Apache Spark - Dealing with Sliding Windows on Temporal RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525272/apache-spark-dealing-with-sliding-windows-on-temporal-rdds)