# Spark SQL: Aggregate with time window

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data ordered by timestamp, with the following structure:

```
+------------+--------+--------+----------+-------+
| timestamp  |  value | device | subgroup | group |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+-------+
| 1377986440 |      0 |      1 |        0 |     5 |
| 1377986440 |   2.25 |      1 |        0 |     5 |
| 1377986440 |      0 |      2 |        0 |     6 |
| 1377986440 |  0.135 |      0 |        0 |     6 |
| 1377986440 |  0.355 |      0 |        0 |     6 |
+------------+--------+--------+----------+-------+
```

I have already changed the timestamp from Long to TimestampType and records go from 1 September 2013 to 30 September 2013.

I need to compute the mean and standard deviation for value over the whole dataset into the following time windows: [00:00, 6:00), [06:00,12:00), [12:00, 18:00), [18:00,00:00) and for each group. For instance, the output should be like this:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-------+
| group |   timeSlot   |  avg |  std  |
+-------+--------------+------+-------+
|     0 | 00:00 6:00   |  1.4 |  0.25 |
|     0 | 06:00 12:00  |  2.4 |  0.25 |
|   ... | ...          | .... |  .... |
|     3 | 00:00 6:00   |  2.3 |   0.1 |
|     3 | 06:00 12:00  |  0.0 |   0.0 |
|   ... | ...          |  ... |   ... |
+-------+--------------+------+-------+
```

I have tried to use window how explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664955/6545142) so i converted my Unix timestamp in a TimestampType with format HH:mm:ss. Then my code is:

```
val data = df
  .select("*")
  .withColumn("timestamp", from_unixtime($"timestamp", "HH:mm:ss"))

 val res = data.select("*")
  .groupBy($"group", window($"timestamp", "6 hours", "6 hours"))
  .agg(avg("value"), stddev("value"))
  .orderBy("group")
```

However the first time slot doesn't start from 00:00 but from 02:00:00 also if I have not specified a starting point for the window. The output I get is:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|group   |window                                    |avg(cons)            |stddev_samp(cons)    |
+--------+------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|0       |[2018-05-18 02:00:00, 2018-05-18 08:00:00]|1.781448366186445E-4 |0.004346229072242386 |
|0       |[2018-05-18 14:00:00, 2018-05-18 20:00:00]|0.0045980360360061865|0.7113464184007158   |
|0       |[2018-05-18 20:00:00, 2018-05-19 02:00:00]|2.7686190915763437E-4|6.490469208721791E-4 |
|0       |[2018-05-17 20:00:00, 2018-05-18 02:00:00]|0.0016399597206953798|0.12325297254169619  |
|0       |[2018-05-18 08:00:00, 2018-05-18 14:00:00]|2.3354306613988956E-4|5.121337883543223E-4 |
|1       |[2018-05-18 20:00:00, 2018-05-19 02:00:00]|8.319111249637333E-4 |0.00163300686441327  |
|1       |[2018-05-18 14:00:00, 2018-05-18 20:00:00]|0.006463708881068344 |0.7907138759032012   |
|1       |[2018-05-18 02:00:00, 2018-05-18 08:00:00]|6.540241054052753E-4 |0.020490123866864617 |
```

How should I change my code? I have tried other solutions but none works

Comment: what is the first record in your dataset (timestamp)?

Comment: @Rumoku  1377986420,0,1,0,3 ; The timestamp is for 1 sept 2013 00:00:20 . However the query should work also on others dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably misconfigured timezone settings. Two hour shift suggests that you use GMT+2 or equivalent.

If you use Spark 2.3 (or later) you can just set timezone in your code (or configuration):

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```