# Advantages of ARIMA with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, arima

I'm new to spark and scala.  I'm working on a project doing forecasting with ARIMA models.  I see from the posts below that I can train ARIMA models with spark.

I'm wondering what's the advantage of using spark for ARIMA models?

[How to do time-series simple forecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248916/how-to-do-time-series-simple-forecast)

https://badrit.com/blog/2017/5/29/time-series-analysis-using-spark#.W9ONGBNKi7M

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of Spark is a distributed processing engine. If you have a huge amount of data which is typically the case in real-life systems, we need such processing engines. It will benefit in terms of scalability and performance to use any algorithm not only ARIMA on platforms like Spark.