# Spark add new column to dataframe with value from previous row

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm wondering how I can achieve the following in Spark (Pyspark)

Initial Dataframe:

```
+--+---+
|id|num|
+--+---+
|4 |9.0|
+--+---+
|3 |7.0|
+--+---+
|2 |3.0|
+--+---+
|1 |5.0|
+--+---+
```

Resulting Dataframe:

```
+--+---+-------+
|id|num|new_Col|
+--+---+-------+
|4 |9.0|  7.0  |
+--+---+-------+
|3 |7.0|  3.0  |
+--+---+-------+
|2 |3.0|  5.0  |
+--+---+-------+
```

I manage to generally "append" new columns to a dataframe by using something like:
`df.withColumn("new_Col", df.num * 10)`

However I have no idea on how I can achieve this "shift of rows" for the new column, so that the new column has the value of a field from the previous row (as shown in the example). I also couldn't find anything in the API documentation on how to access a certain row in a DF by index.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `lag` window function  as follows

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sc.parallelize([(4, 9.0), (3, 7.0), (2, 3.0), (1, 5.0)]).toDF(["id", "num"])
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col("id"))
df.select("*", lag("num").over(w).alias("new_col")).na.drop().show()

## +---+---+-------+
## | id|num|new_col|
## +---+---+-------|
## |  2|3.0|    5.0|
## |  3|7.0|    3.0|
## |  4|9.0|    7.0|
## +---+---+-------+
```

but there some important issues:

1. if you need a global operation (not partitioned by some other column / columns) it is extremely inefficient.
2. you need a natural way to order your data.

While the second issue is almost never a problem the first one can be a deal-breaker. If this is the case you should simply convert your `DataFrame` to RDD and compute `lag` manually. See for example:

- [How to transform data with sliding window over time series data in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685714/1560062)
- [Apache Spark Moving Average](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436517/1560062) (written in Scala, but can be adjusted for PySpark. Be sure to read the comments first).

Other useful links:

- https://github.com/UrbanInstitute/pyspark-tutorials/blob/master/05_moving-average-imputation.ipynb
- [Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates)

Answer (score -1):

```
   val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((4, 9.0), (3, 7.0), (2, 3.0), (1, 5.0))).toDF("id", "num")
df.show
+---+---+
| id|num|
+---+---+
|  4|9.0|
|  3|7.0|
|  2|3.0|
|  1|5.0|
+---+---+
df.withColumn("new_column", lag("num", 1, 0).over(w)).show
+---+---+----------+
| id|num|new_column|
+---+---+----------+
|  1|5.0|       0.0|
|  2|3.0|       5.0|
|  3|7.0|       3.0|
|  4|9.0|       7.0|
+---+---+----------+
```