# How do I get a PySpark DataFrame made using HiveContext in Spark 1.5.2?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Update:  It seems my errors are probably because of how I installed Spark and/or Hive.  Working with window functions seems pretty straightforward in a Databricks (hosted) notebook.  I need to figure out how to set this up locally.

I have a Spark DataFrame that I need to use a Window function on.*  I tried following the instructions over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295642/spark-add-new-column-to-dataframe-with-value-from-previous-row), but I ran into some problems.

Setting up my environment:

```
import os
import sys
import datetime as dt

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = '/usr/bin/spark-1.5.2'
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = '/usr/bin/spark-1.5.2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'
sys.path.append('/usr/bin/spark-1.5.2/python')
sys.path.append('/usr/bin/spark-1.5.2/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
hiveContext = pyspark.sql.HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Setting up my data:

```
test_ts = {'adminDistrict': None,
 'city': None,
 'country': {'code': 'NA', 'name': 'UNKNOWN'},
 'data': [{'timestamp': '2005-08-25T00:00:00Z', 'value': 369.89},
  {'timestamp': '2005-08-26T00:00:00Z', 'value': 362.44},
  {'timestamp': '2005-08-29T00:00:00Z', 'value': 368.3},
  {'timestamp': '2005-08-30T00:00:00Z', 'value': 382.6},
  {'timestamp': '2005-08-31T00:00:00Z', 'value': 377.84},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-01T00:00:00Z', 'value': 380.74},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-02T00:00:00Z', 'value': 370.33},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-05T00:00:00Z', 'value': 370.33},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-06T00:00:00Z', 'value': 361.5},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-07T00:00:00Z', 'value': 352.79},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-08T00:00:00Z', 'value': 354.3},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-09T00:00:00Z', 'value': 353.0},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-12T00:00:00Z', 'value': 349.35},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-13T00:00:00Z', 'value': 348.82},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-14T00:00:00Z', 'value': 360.24},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-15T00:00:00Z', 'value': 357.61},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-16T00:00:00Z', 'value': 347.14},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-19T00:00:00Z', 'value': 370.0},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-20T00:00:00Z', 'value': 362.82},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-21T00:00:00Z', 'value': 366.11},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-22T00:00:00Z', 'value': 364.46},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-23T00:00:00Z', 'value': 351.8},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-26T00:00:00Z', 'value': 360.74},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-27T00:00:00Z', 'value': 356.63},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-28T00:00:00Z', 'value': 363.64},
  {'timestamp': '2005-09-29T00:00:00Z', 'value': 366.05}],
 'maxDate': '2015-12-28T00:00:00Z',
 'minDate': '2005-08-25T00:00:00Z',
 'name': 'S&P GSCI Crude Oil Spot',
 'offset': 0,
 'resolution': 'DAY',
 'sources': ['trf'],
 'subtype': 'Index',
 'type': 'Commodities',
 'uid': 'TRF_INDEX_Z39824_PI'}
```

A function to turn that json into a DataFrame:

```
def ts_to_df(ts):
    data = []
    for line in ts['data']:
        data.append((dt.datetime.strptime(line['timestamp'][:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date(), line['value']))
    return sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['Date', ts['name'].replace('&', '').replace(' ', '_')])
```

Getting a dataframe and taking a look at what's inside:

```
test_df = ts_to_df(test_ts)
test_df.show()
```

That shows me this:

```
+----------+----------------------+
|      Date|SP_GSCI_Crude_Oil_Spot|
+----------+----------------------+
|2005-08-25|                369.89|
|2005-08-26|                362.44|
|2005-08-29|                 368.3|
|2005-08-30|                 382.6|
|2005-08-31|                377.84|
|2005-09-01|                380.74|
|2005-09-02|                370.33|
|2005-09-05|                370.33|
|2005-09-06|                 361.5|
|2005-09-07|                352.79|
|2005-09-08|                 354.3|
|2005-09-09|                 353.0|
|2005-09-12|                349.35|
|2005-09-13|                348.82|
|2005-09-14|                360.24|
|2005-09-15|                357.61|
|2005-09-16|                347.14|
|2005-09-19|                 370.0|
|2005-09-20|                362.82|
|2005-09-21|                366.11|
+----------+----------------------+
```

And here is where I have no idea what I'm doing and everything starts to go wrong:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col, lead
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col('Date'))
test_df.select(lead(test_df.Date, count=1, default=None).over(w).alias("Next_Date")).show()
```

That gives me this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.select.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Could not resolve window function 'lead'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;

So it looks like I need a HiveContext, right?  Do I need to create my DataFrame using a HiveContext?  Then let me try to create a DataFrame explicitly using HiveContext:

```
def ts_to_hive_df(ts):
    data = []
    for line in ts['data']:
        data.append({'Date':dt.datetime.strptime(line['timestamp'][:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
                 ts['name'].replace('&', '').replace(' ', '_'):line['value']})
    temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: Row(**x))
    return hiveContext.createDataFrame(temp_rdd)

test_df = ts_to_hive_df(test_ts)
test_df.show()
```

But that gives me this error:

> TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

So how do I use Window functions?  Do I need to create the DataFrames using a HiveContext?  If so, then how do I do that?  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

*I need to know if there are gaps in my data.  I have the column 'Date' and for each row, ordered by Date, I want to know what's on the next row, and if I have missing days or bad data, then I want to use the last day's data on that row.  If you know of a better way of doing that, let me know.  But I still would like to know how to get these Window functions working.

Comment: Sorry.  Added specific code.  I hope that leads us somewhere.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Alright, well it looks like something might be messed up with how I have Spark (or Hive?) installed locally, because I can get this to work in a DataBricks notebook.  DataBricks doesn't want us making our own HiveContexts or SQLContexts.  To get it working there, I left out the creation of my own contexts and I used the above ts_to_hive_df function, replacing my hiveContext with their sqlContext.  I'll have to get this working in my own install eventually.  I'll come back and write a solution when I figure it out.

Comment: It looks like you're Spark binaries have been built without Hive support.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question and thus moot since you've probably moved onto new versions of Spark.  I'm running spark 2.0 myself, so this may be cheating.

But fwiw: 2 possible issues. In the first example, I think the `.toDF()` maybe defaulting to SQLContext since you had both called.  In the second, when you refactored, could it be that you are calling the hivecontext inside the function?

If I refactor your second `ts_to_df` function  to have  hivecontext called outside the function, everything is fine.

```
def ts_to_df(ts):
    data = []
    for line in ts['data']:
        data.append({'Date':dt.datetime.strptime(line['timestamp'][:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
                 ts['name'].replace('&', '').replace(' ', '_'):line['value']})
    return data

data = ts_to_df(test_ts)
test_rdd = sc.parallelize(data).map(lambda x: Row(**x))
test_df = hiveContext.createDataFrame(test_rdd)

from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, col, lead
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col('Date'))
test_df.select(lead(test_df.Date, count=1, default=None).over(w).alias("Next_Date")).show()
```

I get the output

```
+----------+
| Next_Date|
+----------+
|2005-08-26|
|2005-08-29|
|2005-08-30|
|2005-08-31|
|2005-09-01|
|2005-09-02|
.....
```