# Calculating integral using Spark and DataFrames

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, integral

I have a Spark `DataFrame` representing energy consumption (in kW) of particular device in particular moment (datestamped). I would like to calculate energy consumption in kWh, it means calculate integral over this dataset for a given time interval. How can I accomplish it using Spark?

Comment: How do you want to estimate the energy consumption? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to calculate sum of area of every trapezoid between two datapoints (areas below linear functions through two consecutive datapoints). I'm still searching and haven't try anything yet.

Comment: Window functions should be able to help. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html. Here's an example of how to get lagged values (lead values would be similar) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295642/spark-add-new-column-to-dataframe-with-value-from-previous-row?rq=1

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem.