# Spark Window function last not null value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have a times series database for user events, which looks like the following:

```
timestamp             user_id     event            ticke_type     error_type 
2019-06-06 14:33:31   user_a      choose_ticket    ticke_b        NULL
2019-06-06 14:34:31   user_b      choose_ticket    ticke_f        NULL
2019-06-06 14:36:31   user_a      booing_error     NULL           error_c  
2019-06-06 14:37:31   user_a      choose_ticket    ticke_h        NULL
2019-06-06 14:38:31   user_a      booing_error     NULL           error_d
2019-06-06 14:39:31   user_a      booing_error     NULL           error_e
```

This is one usecase that we need:

In order to investigate what kind of ticket type is causing some booking error, 
we will have to look into the ticket type,
which is available only on the earlier event `choose_ticket`.

In this case, what we are looking is for each `booking_error` event, find the previous `choose_ticket` event
for the same user and merge the ticket type there to the `booking_error` event.

So ideally, the output that we want is:

```
timestamp             user_id     event            ticke_type     error_type 
2019-06-06 14:36:31   user_a      booing_error     ticke_b        error_c  
2019-06-06 14:38:31   user_a      booing_error     ticke_h        error_d
2019-06-06 14:39:31   user_a      booing_error     ticke_h        error_e
```

The closest that I can find is [Spark add new column to dataframe with value from previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295642/spark-add-new-column-to-dataframe-with-value-from-previous-row/34296063#34296063),
which allows us to take the properties from a previous event and apply it to the event right after.

This works almost, except that when there are multiple events (`booing_error` in this example), only the very first one can get the needed properties in this case. 
e.g., this what we will get with the solution from the SO link above:

```
timestamp             user_id     event            ticke_type     error_type 
2019-06-06 14:36:31   user_a      booing_error     ticke_b        error_c  
2019-06-06 14:38:31   user_a      booing_error     ticke_h        error_d
2019-06-06 14:39:31   user_a      booing_error     NULL           error_e
```

To sum up, for a given row, how to find the previous row matching certain criteria and "cherry-pick" its property over?

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.last` is what you are looking for. You may rename the "closest" column to replace ticke_type in the end.

```
scala> df.show
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+
|          timestamp|user_id|        event|ticke_type|error_type|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+
|2019-06-06 14:33:31| user_a|choose_ticket|   ticke_b|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:34:31| user_b|choose_ticket|   ticke_f|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:36:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_c|
|2019-06-06 14:37:31| user_a|choose_ticket|   ticke_h|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:38:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_d|
|2019-06-06 14:39:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_e|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+

scala> val overColumns = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("timestamp")
overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@70dc8c9a

scala> df.withColumn("closest", 
  org.apache.spark.sql.functions.last("ticke_type", true).over(overColumns)).filter($"event" === "booking_error").show
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
|          timestamp|user_id|        event|ticke_type|error_type|closest|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
|2019-06-06 14:36:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_c|ticke_b|
|2019-06-06 14:38:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_d|ticke_h|
|2019-06-06 14:39:31| user_a|booking_error|      null|   error_e|ticke_h|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is pyspark version

```py
 df = self.spark.createDataFrame(
            [('2019-06-06 14:33:31', 'user_a', 'choose_ticket', 'ticke_b', None),
             ('2019-06-06 14:34:31', 'user_b', 'choose_ticket', 'ticke_f', None),
             ('2019-06-06 14:36:31', 'user_a', 'booing_error', None, 'error_c'),
             ('2019-06-06 14:37:31', 'user_a', 'choose_ticket', 'ticke_h', None),
             ('2019-06-06 14:38:31', 'user_a', 'booing_error', None, 'error_d'),
             ('2019-06-06 14:39:31', 'user_a', 'booing_error', None, 'error_e'),
             ],
            ("timestamp", "user_id", "event", "ticke_type", "error_type"))

        df.show()

        window_spec = Window.partitionBy(col("user_id")).orderBy(col("timestamp"))

        df = df.withColumn('ticke_type_forwardfill', when(col("event") == "choose_ticket", col("ticke_type")) \
                           .otherwise(last("ticke_type", True).over(window_spec))) \
            .drop(col("ticke_type")) \
            .filter(col("event") == "booing_error")

        df.show()
```

result

```
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+
|          timestamp|user_id|        event|ticke_type|error_type|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+
|2019-06-06 14:33:31| user_a|choose_ticket|   ticke_b|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:34:31| user_b|choose_ticket|   ticke_f|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:36:31| user_a| booing_error|      null|   error_c|
|2019-06-06 14:37:31| user_a|choose_ticket|   ticke_h|      null|
|2019-06-06 14:38:31| user_a| booing_error|      null|   error_d|
|2019-06-06 14:39:31| user_a| booing_error|      null|   error_e|
+-------------------+-------+-------------+----------+----------+

+-------------------+-------+------------+----------+----------------------+
|          timestamp|user_id|       event|error_type|ticke_type_forwardfill|
+-------------------+-------+------------+----------+----------------------+
|2019-06-06 14:36:31| user_a|booing_error|   error_c|               ticke_b|
|2019-06-06 14:38:31| user_a|booing_error|   error_d|               ticke_h|
|2019-06-06 14:39:31| user_a|booing_error|   error_e|               ticke_h|
+-------------------+-------+------------+----------+----------------------+
```