# How to convert ArrayType to DenseVector in PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm getting the following error trying to build a ML `Pipeline`:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually ArrayType(DoubleType,true).'
```

My `features` column contains an array of floating point values. It sounds like I need to convert those to some type of vector (it's not sparse, so a DenseVector?). Is there a way to do this directly on the DataFrame or do I need to convert to an RDD?

Comment: I was stuck on the same thing while calculating the vector norm. I used `array_to_vector` from `pyspark.ml.functions` to convert the array column to a vector type. Only available in **pyspark>=3.1.0**. More details here: stackoverflow.com/a/48333361/2650427.

Answer (score 28):

You can use UDF:

```
udf(lambda vs: Vectors.dense(vs), VectorUDT())
```

In Spark < 2.0 import:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

In Spark 2.0+ import:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
```

Please note that these classes are not compatible despite identical implementation.

It is also possible to extract individual features and assemble with `VectorAssembler`. Assuming input column is called `features`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

n = ... # Size of features

assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["features[{0}]".format(i) for i in range(n)], 
    outputCol="features_vector")

assembler.transform(df.select(
    "*", *(df["features"].getItem(i) for i in range(n))
))
```