# Bad formation of VectorAssembler giving unwanted values into features

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, feature-extraction, apache-spark-ml

I've used `VectorAssembler` many times which worked well. But today I got unwanted data into features as shown in below in figure.

Input is 4 features without NaN which are from pySpark data frame.

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = descritif.columns, outputCol = 'features')
pcaFeatures = assembler.transform(descritif).select('features')
pcaFeatures.show(truncate=False)
```

Why I've got `(5,[0,1]` before every rows in features column, is this normal?
Does it affect learning?
[image: vector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To come up to my problem after two day I found solution. There two post in stack which did not give effective solution.

1 - First Aplied this udf function to convert data.

## function

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector

def sparse_to_array(v):
  v = DenseVector(v)
  new_array = list([float(x) for x in v])
  return new_array

sparse_to_array_udf = F.udf(sparse_to_array, T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))
```

2 - Then apply it to the data.
 # convert

```
df = pcaFeatures.withColumn('features_array', sparse_to_array_udf('features'))
```

Then If you want to convert this matrix to Vector pleas visit this website.
[Convert in Vector](https://webdevdesigner.com/q/pyspark-how-do-i-convert-an-array-i-e-list-column-to-vector-81349/) because after this step you can end up with a sparse matrix not vector then you'll get this error (below)  on PCA or other while fitting/transform the data.

> IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Column pcaFeatures_Norm
>   must be of type
>   struct,values:array>
>   but was actually array.'

Comment: There are alternative ways to get the dense vectors. I had the same problem and this post solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025707/how-to-convert-arraytype-to-densevector-in-pyspark-dataframe