# Pyspark: expanding dataset to include neighbours

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark and trying to migrate an existing python application to pyspark.

One of the first functions (in this case `f(x)`) should run for every element in the dataset, but should also take into account other elements in the dataset.

the best simplification I could get this to is the following pseudo-code:

```
    def idx_gen_a(x):
        return x-5

    def idx_gen_b(x):
        return x*3

    def f(i, x, dataset):
        elem1 = dataset.get(idx_gen_a(i))
        elem2 = dataset.get(idx_gen_b(i))
        ...
        return some_calculation(x, elem1, elem2, ...)

    def main(dataset):
        result = []
        for i, x in enumerate(dataset):
            result.append(f(i, x,dataset))
```

Is there a Spark-ish way of doing this? `foreachPartition` and `aggregate` din't seem to quite fit..

Comment: Take a look at [How to transform data with sliding window over time series data in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31685714/10465355)

Comment: @user10465355, thanks, I have looked at sparksql's window functionality, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to this case..

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're calling `dataset.get` maps roughly to a `join` in spark. I've written a rough translation of you're above code using pyspark and RDDs. `f1` and `f2` are your two functions. You could do something very similar using dataframes.

```
data = spark.range(10).rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], row[0] * 10))

def unNest(nested):
  key, ((v1, v2), v3) = nested
  return key, (v1, v2, v3)

def f1(a): return a + 1
def f2(a): return a - 1

one = data.map(lambda pair: (f1(pair[0]), pair[1]))
two = data.map(lambda pair: (f2(pair[0]), pair[1]))
data.join(one).join(two).map(unNest).take(10)

# [(1, (10, 0, 20)),
#  (2, (20, 10, 30)),
#  (3, (30, 20, 40)),
#  (4, (40, 30, 50)),
#  (5, (50, 40, 60)),
#  (6, (60, 50, 70)),
#  (7, (70, 60, 80)),
#  (8, (80, 70, 90))]
```

There are different types of joins, for example inner vs outer, but I hope this is enough to point you in the right direction.