# Xml processing in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Scenario:
My Input will be multiple small XMLs and am Supposed to read these XMLs as RDDs. Perform join with another dataset and form an RDD and send the output as an XML.

Is it possible to read XML using spark, load the data as RDD? If it is possible how will the XML be read.

Sample XML:

```
<root>
    <users>
        <user>
              <account>1234<\account>
              <name>name_1<\name>
              <number>34233<\number>
         <\user>
         <user>
              <account>58789<\account>
              <name>name_2<\name>
              <number>54697<\number>
         <\user>    
    <\users>
<\root>
```

How will this be loaded into the RDD?

Comment: BTW, your XML isn't XML at all. You need to replace all `\\` to `/`

Comment: Hi Pavani! I'm starting with this exercise on Spark, and I want to know the Solutions to go more advanced on class, Could you help me please?

Answer (score 23):

Yes it possible but details will differ depending on an approach you take.

- If files are small, as you've mentioned, the simplest solution is to load your data using `SparkContext.wholeTextFiles`. It loads data as `RDD[(String, String)]` where the the first element is path and the second file content. Then you parse each file individually like in a local mode.
- For larger files you can use [Hadoop input formats](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat).

  - If structure is simple you can split records using `textinputformat.record.delimiter`. You can find a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31229843/1560062). Input is not a XML but it you should give you and idea how to proceed
  - Otherwise Mahout provides [`XmlInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java)
- Finally it is possible to read file using `SparkContext.textFile` and adjust later for record spanning between partitions. Conceptually it means something similar to creating sliding window or [partitioning records into groups of fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072089/1560062):

  - use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` partitions to identify records broken between partitions, collect broken records
  - use second `mapPartitionsWithIndex` to repair broken records

**Edit**:

There is also relatively new [`spark-xml`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) package which allows you to extract specific records by tag:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
   .option("rowTag", "foo")
   .load("bar.xml")
```

Comment: So, how would the broken records be fixed ?

Comment: How would you handle the nested keys within the XML and bring them to the same level?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the way to perform it using `HadoopInputFormats` to read XML data in spark as explained by @zero323.

**Input data:**

```
<root>
    <users>
        <user>
            <account>1234<\account>
            <name>name_1<\name>
            <number>34233<\number>
        <\user>
        <user>
            <account>58789<\account>
            <name>name_2<\name>
            <number>54697<\number>
        <\user>
    <\users>
<\root>
```

**Code for reading XML Input:**

You will get some jars at this [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6JD1IP1D-GONWtGZTZlR2c2MVk&usp=sharing)

Imports:

```scala
//---------------spark_import
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

//----------------xml_loader_import
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{ LongWritable, Text }
import com.cloudera.datascience.common.XmlInputFormat
```

Code:

```scala
object Tester_loader {
  case class User(account: String, name: String, number: String)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkHome = "/usr/big_data_tools/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/"
    val sparkMasterUrl = "spark://SYSTEMX:7077"

    var jars = new Array[String](3)

    jars(0) = "/home/hduser/Offload_Data_Warehouse_Spark.jar"
    jars(1) = "/usr/big_data_tools/JARS/Spark_jar/avro/spark-avro_2.10-2.0.1.jar"

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("XML Reading")
    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .setMaster("local")
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .setSparkHome(sparkHome)
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "512m")
      .set("spark.default.deployCores", "12")
      .set("spark.cores.max", "12")
      .setJars(jars)

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    // ---- loading user from XML

    // calling function 1.1
    val pages = readFile("src/input_data", "<user>", "<\\user>", sc) 

    val xmlUserDF = pages.map { tuple =>
      {
        val account = extractField(tuple, "account")
        val name = extractField(tuple, "name")
        val number = extractField(tuple, "number")

        User(account, name, number)
      }
    }.toDF()
    println(xmlUserDF.count())
    xmlUserDF.show()
  }
```

Functions:

```scala
  def readFile(path: String, start_tag: String, end_tag: String,
      sc: SparkContext) = {

    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, start_tag)
    conf.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, end_tag)
    val rawXmls = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
        path, classOf[XmlInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable],
        classOf[Text], conf)

    rawXmls.map(p => p._2.toString)
  }

  def extractField(tuple: String, tag: String) = {
    var value = tuple.replaceAll("\n", " ").replace("<\\", "</")

    if (value.contains("<" + tag + ">") &&
        value.contains("</" + tag + ">")) {
      value = value.split("<" + tag + ">")(1).split("</" + tag + ">")(0)
    }
    value
  }

}
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+------+------+
|account|  name|number|
+-------+------+------+
|   1234|name_1| 34233|
|  58789|name_2| 54697|
+-------+------+------+
```

The result obtained is in dataframes you can convert them to RDD as per your requirement like this->

```scala
val xmlUserRDD = xmlUserDF.toJavaRDD.rdd.map { x =>
    (x.get(0).toString(),x.get(1).toString(),x.get(2).toString()) }
```

Please evaluate it, if it could help you some how.

Answer (score 5):

This will help you.

```
package packagename;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader;

public class XmlreaderSpark {
    public static void main(String arr[]){
    String localxml="file path";
    String booksFileTag = "user";

    String warehouseLocation = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "spark-warehouse";
   System.out.println("warehouseLocation" + warehouseLocation);
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .master("local")
              .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
              .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
              .enableHiveSupport().config("set spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
              .getOrCreate();
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(spark);

    Dataset<Row> df = (new XmlReader()).withRowTag(booksFileTag).xmlFile(sqlContext, localxml);
    df.show();

    }
}
```

You need to add this dependency in your POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-xml_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and your input file is not in proper format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two good options for simple cases:

- `wholeTextFiles`. Use map method with your XML parser which could be Scala XML pull parser (quicker to code) or the SAX Pull Parser (better performance).
- `Hadoop streaming XMLInputFormat` which you must define the start and end tag `<user>` `</user>` to process it, however, it creates one partition per user tag
- `spark-xml package` is a good option too.

With all options you are limited to only process simple XMLs which can be interpreted as dataset with rows and columns.

However, if we make it a little complex, those options won’t be useful.

For example, if you have one more entity there:

```
<root>
    <users>
    <user>...</users>
    <companies>
    <company>...</companies>
</root>
```

Now you need to generate 2 RDDs and change your parser to recognise the `<company>` tag.

This is just a simple case, but the XML could be much more complex and you would need to include more and more changes.

To solve this complexity we’ve built Flexter on top of Apache Spark to take the pain out of [processing XML files on Spark](https://sonra.io/2016/09/08/take-the-pain-out-of-xml-processing-on-spark/). I also recommend to read about [converting XML on Spark to Parquet](https://sonra.io/2018/01/25/convert-xml-with-spark-to-parquet/). The latter post also includes some code samples that show how the output can be queried with SparkSQL.

Disclaimer: I work for Sonra

Comment: I suggest you add a disclaimer that you are the co-founder of this company.