# Use Apache Spark to implement the python function

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python code to implement in Spark, however I am unable to get the logic right for the RDD working to implement in Spark 1.1 version. This code is perfectly working in Python ,but I would like to implement in Spark with this code.

```
import lxml.etree
import csv

sc = SparkContext
data = sc.textFile("pain001.xml")
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
# compile xpath selectors for ele ment text
selectors = ('GrpHdr/MsgId', 'GrpHdr/CreDtTm') # etc...
xpath = [lxml.etree.XPath('{}/text()'.format(s)) for s in selectors]

# open result csv file
with open('pain.csv', 'w') as paincsv:
    writer = csv.writer(paincsv)
    # read file with 1 'CstmrCdtTrfInitn' record per line
    with open(rdd) as painxml:
        # process each record
        for index, line in enumerate(painxml):
            if not line.strip(): # allow empty lines
                continue
            try:
                # each line is an xml doc
                pain001 = lxml.etree.fromstring(line)
                # move to the customer elem
                elem = pain001.find('CstmrCdtTrfInitn')
                # select each value and write to csv
                writer.writerow([xp(elem)[0].strip() for xp in xpath])
            except Exception, e:
                # give a hint where things go bad
                sys.stderr.write("Error line {}, {}".format(index, str(e)))
                raise  

I am getting error as RDD not iteratable
```

1. I want to implement this code as a function and implement as a standalone program in Spark
2. I would want the input file  to be processed in HDFS as well as local mode in Spark with the python module.

Appreciate responses for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is very informative, when you do `with open(rdd) as painxml:` and after that, you try to `iterate` over the `RDD` as if it was a normal `List` or `Tuple` in python, and an `RDD` is not `iterable`, furthermore if you read the [textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.SparkContext.textFile) documentation, you can notice that it returns an `RDD`.

I think the problem you have is that you are trying to achieve this in a classic way, and you must approach it inside the `MapReduce` paradigm, if you are really new into `Apache Spark`, you can audit this course [Scalable Machine Learning with Apache Spark](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-big-data-apache-spark-uc-berkeleyx-cs100-1x), furthermore I would recommend you to update your spark's version to 1.5 or 1.6 (that will come out soon).

Just as a small example (but not using xmls):

1. Import the required files

   ```
   import re
   import csv
   ```
2. Read the input file

   ```
   content = sc.textFile("../test")
   content.collect()
   # Out[8]: [u'1st record-1', u'2nd record-2', u'3rd record-3', u'4th record-4']
   ```
3. `Map` the `RDD` to manipulate each row

   ```
   # Map it and convert it to tuples
   rdd = content.map(lambda s: tuple(re.split("-+",s)))
   rdd.collect()
   # Out[9]: [(u'1st record', u'1'),
   #          (u'2nd record', u'2'),
   #          (u'3rd record', u'3'),
   #          (u'4th record', u'4')]
   ```
4. Write your data

   ```
   with open("../test.csv", "w") as fw:
       writer = csv.writer(fw)

       for r1 in rdd.toLocalIterator():
           writer.writerow(r1)
   ```
5. Take a look...

   ```
   $ cat test.csv
   1st record,1
   2nd record,2
   3rd record,3
   4th record,4
   ```

Note: If you want to read a `xml` with `Apache Spark`, there are some libraries in GitHub like [spark-xml](https://github.com/HyukjinKwon/spark-xml); you can also find this question interesting [xml processing in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078221/xml-processing-in-spark).

Comment: Thanks Alberto, However would you mind to share a logic where it could be implemented in spark using python

Comment: @user5697452 I added an example but not using xml, but the path is there!