# Parse XML data in Apache Spark

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, apache-spark, streaming

I need to know how to how to parse XML file in Spark. I am receiving streaming data from kafka and then need to parse that streamed data.

Here is my Spark code to receive data:

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd ->{
            rdd.foreach(s ->{
                System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&" +s._2 );
            });
```

And results:

```
<root>
<student>
<name>john</name>
<marks>90</marks>
</student>
</root>
```

How to pass these XML elements?

Comment: Have you searched for previous questions on this? Such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078221/xml-processing-in-spark

Comment: @Binary Nerd, Thanks for response. My spark application is reading data line by line. So i need to parse line by line without using start element and/or end element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks guys.. Problem Solved.
Here is the solution.

```
String xml = "<name>xyz</name>";
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
try {
    parser.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(xml)));
    Document doc = parser.getDocument();
    String message = doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
    System.out.println(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle SAXException 
}
```

Comment: @MasudRahman, please look at the mentioned link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078221/xml-processing-in-spark/40653300#40653300

Answer (score 2):

As you are processing streaming data, it would be helpful to use databricks's spark-xml lib for xml data processing.

Reference: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Comment: Thanks for response. My spark application is reading data line by line. So i need to parse line by line without using start element and/or end element.

Comment: I spent couple of hours with this, and then I found it does not read self-closing rows.