# Apache Spark's RDD splitting according to the particular size

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to read strings from a text file, but I want to limit each line according to a particular size. For example;

Here is my representing the file.

> aaaaa\nbbb\nccccc

When trying to read this file by sc.textFile, RDD would appear this one.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("textFile")
scala> rdd.collect
res1: Array[String] = Array(aaaaa, bbb, ccccc)
```

But I want to limit the size of this RDD. For example, if the limit is 3, then I should get like this one.

```
Array[String] = Array(aaa, aab, bbc, ccc, c)
```

What is the best performance way to do that?

Comment: So you want to ignore line boundaries and split into `n` character groups? It's almost certainly going to be quicker to preprocess this outside Spark into lines of length `n` then read that in with `textFile`

Answer (score 3):

Not a particularly efficient solution (not terrible either) but you can do something like this:

```
val pairs = rdd
  .flatMap(x => x)  // Flatten
  .zipWithIndex  // Add indices
  .keyBy(_._2 / 3)  // Key by index / n

// We'll use a range partitioner to minimize the shuffle 
val partitioner = new RangePartitioner(pairs.partitions.size, pairs)

pairs
  .groupByKey(partitioner)  // group
  // Sort, drop index, concat
  .mapValues(_.toSeq.sortBy(_._2).map(_._1).mkString("")) 
  .sortByKey()
  .values
```

It is possible to avoid the shuffle by passing data required to fill the partitions explicitly but it takes some effort to code. See my answer to [Partition RDD into tuples of length n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072089/1560062).

If you can accept some misaligned records on partitions boundaries then simple `mapPartitions` with grouped should do the trick at much lower cost:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(_.flatMap(x => x).grouped(3).map(_.mkString("")))
```

It is also possible to use sliding RDD:

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x).sliding(3, 3).map(_.mkString(""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read all the data anyhow. Not much you can do apart from mapping each line and trim it.

```
rdd.map(line => line.take(3)).collect()
```

Comment: I don't think this is it. Take another look at the expected output.