# PySpark join shuffles co-partitioned RDDs

Tags: join, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)], numSlices=8)
rdd2 = rdd1.mapValues(lambda x: x)
```

These RDDs have the same partitioning:

```
rdd1.keys().glom().collect()
>>> [[], ['a'], [], ['b'], [], ['c'], [], ['d']]

rdd2.keys().glom().collect()
>>> [[], ['a'], [], ['b'], [], ['c'], [], ['d']]
```

There's multiple answers here on SO that suggest that joining co-partitioned data will not cause a shuffle, which makes a lot of sense to me. Example: [Does a join of co-partitioned RDDs cause a shuffle in Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395376/does-a-join-of-co-partitioned-rdds-cause-a-shuffle-in-apache-spark)

However, when I join these co-partitioned RDDs using PySpark, the data is shuffled into a new partition:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).keys().glom().collect()
>>> [['a'], [], ['c'], ['b'], [], ['d'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

And the partitioning changes even when I set the number of new partitions to the original 8:

```
rdd1.join(rdd2, numPartitions=8).keys().glom().collect()
>>> [['a'], [], ['c'], ['b'], [], ['d'], [], []]
```

How come I can't avoid a shuffle using these co-partitioned RDDs?

I'm using Spark 1.6.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case neither `rdd1` nor `rdd2` is partitioned

```py
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
rdd2 = rdd1.mapValues(lambda x: x)

rdd1.partitioner is None
## True

rdd2.partitioner is None
# True
```

so by definition there are not co-partitioned. While you could partition data and join:

```py
n = rdd1.getNumPartitions()
rdd1part = rdd1.partitionBy(n)
rdd2part = rdd2.partitionBy(n)

rdd1part.join(rdd2part)  # rdd1part and rdd2part are co-partitioned
```

this would simply rearrange DAG and won't prevent shuffle.

See also [Default Partitioning Scheme in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34491219/1560062)

Comment: Thanks, this might just solve the problem I'm facing. I'm surprised, though, that settings `numSlices` does not imply an explicit partitioning. (I guess now I understand why it's not called `numPartitions`, like in other functions.)

Comment: When we talk about partitions in Spark we mean two different concepts. You can check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34491219/1560062 for some explanation.