# moving average - stddev for multiple feators in single vector column

Tags: apache-spark

I need to calculate a moving average and stddev for 20 fields. I came up with the following windowed query ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674817/203968)) .

```scala
val w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("cykle").rowsBetween(0, windowRange)

val x = withrul.select('*,
                   mean($"s1").over(w).as("a1"), 
                   sqrt( sum(pow($"s1" -  mean($"s1").over(w),2)).over(w) / 5).as("sd1"),
                   ... repeat 19 times more
```

Is there a way of doing this with a single vector column (feature vector) ?