# Spark Streaming with window of N elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

In Spark Streaming, using Scala or Java, how can I have a stream that always contains the most recent `N` elements?

I'm familiar with the possibility to create windowed streams, using methods such as `window(windowLength, slideInterval)`. Here, both `windowLength` and `slideInterval` are time intervals. Is there an equivalent where you specify a row (i.e. element) count for the length and interval of a stream?

If there is no provided API for such cases, how would you go about implementing it yourself?

Comment: As in the last value for a given field or top N? E.g. for all customers, the total sales to-date you mean? Unclear.

Comment: @thebluephantom In a continuous stream of live data (such as, data from Kafka), the `N` `DataFrames` or `DataSets` that that have been emitted most recently. Does that clear it up for you?

Comment: not really, provide an example. just copy you mean?

Comment: I doubt code makes it clearer if that description didn't do it. Anyway, for example analogous to `DStream::reduceByWindow`, the following: `val intStream: DStream[Int] = createStream(); val sumOfLastValues: DStream[Int] = intStream.reduceByCount(howMany, howOften, _ + _)`

Comment: Examples are better than code imho.

Comment: That code IS an example. I'm afraid that's all I can do

Comment: I guess we will have to see how others see it. Good luck.

Comment: @thebluephantom I had another idea as an example: Continuously calculate the the moving average of a DStream[Int] (or structured stream with Ints) for further processing, creating a new stream of moving average Ints. If you can solve that efficiently, you are a ninja. I tried for hours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402303

Comment: Thanks, but that only works on a finite `RDD` not on a continuous stream like a `DStream`, as much as I'd like it to

Comment: But it does state Spark Streaming and there are many links.

Comment: Unless that's the wrong link, the phrase "stream" does not occur once on the linked page, and that one only works for `RDD`s

Comment: rephrase your question as to wgat you seek with which streaming approach

Comment: I note no answer(s), so I suggest you re-phrase before I give you the possible solution.

Comment: The question is clear, and I have provided multiple clarifications and examples for you in the comments. If you have learned something since your last attempted solution, feel free to post an answer

Comment: But what about this comment:  I had another idea as an example: Continuously calculate the the moving average of a DStream[Int] (or structured stream with Ints) for further processing, creating a new stream of moving average Ints. If you can solve that efficiently, you are a ninja. I tried for hours – ig-dev Mar 29 at 3:19

Comment: What about it? You asked for an example